# How to read an installed feature (eclipse PDE)?

Tags: eclipse, pde

Is it possible to read a feature like its possible to read a plugin use the eclipse PDE API? Currently I read plugins using:

```
        Bundle[] bundles = Platform.getBundles(name, version);
        if (bundles == null) {
          throw new NullPointerException("No bundle found with ID: " + name
              + " and version: " + version);

        } else {
          for (Bundle bundle : bundles) {
            System.out.println(bundle.getSymbolicName());

          }

        }
```

But if I specify the name of an installed feature I just get null. Is there some other way that features should be read?

And when I have read the feature I would like to iterate all the plugins that it reference.

Comment: Bundles refer to plugins, not to features. Features are logical units used for installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use p2 API to query the installed feature. P2 is the manager of eclipse installation.

```
// IProvisioningAgent is a OSGi service
IProvisioningAgent agent = ...;
IProfileRegistry profileRegistry = (IProfileRegistry) agent.getService(IProfileRegistry.SERVICE_NAME);
IProfile profile = profileRegistry.getProfile(IProfileRegistry.SELF);
IQueryResult rt = profile.query(QueryUtil.createIUPropertyQuery("org.eclipse.equinox.p2.eclipse.type", "feature"), null);
```